# Add constraint to table creation in SQL

Tags: mysql, table, constraint, check-constraints

I have to create a table Product with elements P, PType, PName, Price and Origin.

I need to have the constraint that all products with PType "Meat" must have "Europe" as Origin. I wanted to add the constraint in an alter table but I saw that using an alter table means modifying the original table after its creation, but I need to have this condition at the creation of the table. I don't know how to write this constraint, can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Do you want: option 1 - if `PType = "Meat"` but `Origin != "Europe"` then fail the query; option 2 - if `PType = "Meat"` then set `Origin = "Europe"` despite of assigned value (no fail).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN MySQL 8 (>= [8.0.16](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint/)) You can use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`

In older Versions you will need an `INSERT/UPDATE TRIGGER`

That said, you should also normalize your table and use a lookup (or reference/helper) table for an Origin id and a Type id.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Product 
> ( 
>     P INT 
>   , PType varchar(19)
>   , PName varchar(20)
>   , Price DECIMAL(8,2)
>   , Origin varchar(50)
>   , CONSTRAINT CHK_type CHECK ((Ptype = 'meat' AND Origin ='Europe') 
>                            OR Ptype <> 'meat' )
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Product VALUES (1,'meat','Kobe Beef',10000.00,'Japan')
> ```
>
> ```
> Check constraint 'CHK_type' is violated.
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Product VALUES (1,'apple','Breaburn',10.00,'New Zealand')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e1fad4c27e5c940981edf516cfa058f0)*

Comment: Thank you so much, it has been very helpful!

Comment: The constraint can be simplified to `CHECK (Origin = 'Europe' OR Ptype <> 'meat')` but I admit that your version is much more clear.